# Find all poles, and their residues, as functions of a?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have to find poles and residues as functions of a for the following function:

$\frac{1}{e^z-a}$

But I'm not sure where to start. I know how to find poles and residues but not when I'm given an arbitrary function with an unknown, a, in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know what the poles and residues are for $a\in\{0,1\}$?

Comment: The poles would be ln(a)? What about residues?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you interpreted my hint correctly, so here's  different one: the DLMF [lists](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36#E5) the partial fraction decomposition of the function $\mathrm{csch}\, z$.

Comment: @KBDave in what way does that relate? I'm struggling to see that!

Comment: Sorry, I'll try and write a more lucid answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that there are countable many poles                           , each of order 1 for $a\neq 0$. [ Some very basic knowledge of logarithms gives this. To  see that poles are of order 1 just check that the derivative of $e^{z} -a$ does not  vanish at $z_0$ if $e^{z_0} =a$]. Now the residue  of $\frac 1 {e^{z}-a}$ at any pole $z_0$ is given by the limit as $z\to z_0$ of $(z-z_0)\frac 1 {e^{z}-a}$ which, by L'Hopital's Rule  is $\frac 1 {e^{z_0}} =\frac 1 a$. [I leave it to you to write down the poles explicitly using logarithms].

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a\neq 0$. Let $f(z)=\tfrac{1}{\mathrm{e}^z-1}$. Then
$$\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^z-a}=a^{-1}f(z-\ln a)$$
so it suffices to consider the residues of $f$ alone. The partial fraction decompositions in the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36) tell us what to expect:

$$f(z)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2z}{z^2+(2n\pi)^2}\text{.}$$
That is, at each zero of $\mathrm{e}^z-1$ there is a simple pole of residue $1$. To show this, it suffices to think about the behavior near $z=0$ since $f(z)$ is periodic. Note that the Maclaurin expansion of $\mathrm{e}^z-1$ starts off as
$$\mathrm{e}^z-1=z+O(z)\text{.}$$
Taking the reciprocal of this expression, the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ must start off as
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+O(1)\text{.}$$